# How to fit svg to image

Tags: html, xml, svg

I want to use a svg inside image tag as below

```
<img src="test.svg" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;">
```

and my "test.svg" is:

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" ?><!DOCTYPE svg  PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN'  'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'>
 <svg width="24px" height="24px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <path d="M4,10h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2s-0.896-2-2-2H4C2.896,6,2,6.896,2,8S2.896,10,4,10z M28,14H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2  s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2S29.104,14,28,14z M28,22H4c-1.104,0-2,0.896-2,2s0.896,2,2,2h24c1.104,0,2-0.896,2-2  S29.104,22,28,22z"/>
 </svg>
```

My problem is that the svg doesn't scale and fit to the image tag and get cropped. It seems setting viewport for svg doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: You need a different value for the viewBox: Use this: `viewBox="2 6 28 20"`. In order to know the `viewBox` value you need use the `getBBox()` method for the path.

Comment: @enxaneta it works! I am new to svg and I didn't know about `getBBox()` method. So whenever I want to use an svg, first I should use this method to find the minimium fitting rectangular for that svg and then use it. Am I right?

Comment: This may be useful. However sometimes you may need to add some extra space for very wide strokes of filters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the actual size of your path inside the SVG file is not 24x24 pixels, but 28x20, and is positioned at X=2 and Y=6. (You can use an SVG editor program like Gravit to look these numbers up.) Using that knowledge, setting you viewport to `viewBox="2 6 28 20"` does fix your problem.